# Centre divs horizontally not working inside container div

Tags: html, css, alignment, containers

I've been struggling with this for days but must be missing something stupid, hope you can help!

Basically I am building a site with a header, body and footer. The header div has a flash element embedded and was working fine.
I have all divs centered by using:

```
Position: absolute;
Width: 2000px;
Margin-left: -1000px;
Left: 50%;
```

This worked fine until I tried to get the footer to stay at the bottom of the page but not overlap the rest of the content when resizing. But I got that sorted thanks to StickyFooter, and putting the div outside of the container div, and changing all divs position to 'relative'.

But now everything inside my container does not want to center correctly anymore and I just cant get it right. Any ideas anyone please? Would really appreciate it.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Site</title>
<link href="CSS/lum.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/flexcroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/SpryEffects.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_showHideLayers() { //v9.0
  var i,p,v,obj,args=MM_showHideLayers.arguments;
  for (i=0; i<(args.length-2); i+=3) 
  with (document) if (getElementById && ((obj=getElementById(args[i]))!=null)) { v=args[i+2];
    if (obj.style) { obj=obj.style; v=(v=='show')?'visible':(v=='hide')?'hidden':v; }
    obj.visibility=v; }
}
function MM_effectAppearFade(targetElement, duration, from, to, toggle)
{
    Spry.Effect.DoFade(targetElement, {duration: duration, from: from, to: to, toggle: toggle});
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container" align="center">
    <div id="header">
                <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="2000" height="500" id="lum_topbar" align="middle">
                <param name="movie" value="lum_topbar.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="best" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="lum_topbar.swf" width="2000" height="500">
                    <param name="movie" value="lum_topbar.swf" />
                    <param name="quality" value="best" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                    <param name="play" value="true" />
                    <param name="loop" value="true" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="menu" value="true" />
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                    <param name="salign" value="" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
    </div>

    <iframe name="ifcontent" id="ifcontent" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" src="home.html"></iframe>

</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer_img"><img src="images/footer.jpg" alt="footer" width="2000" height="227" usemap="#Map" border="0" />
    <map name="Map" id="Map">
      <area shape="rect" coords="961,32,1019,55" href="design.html" target="ifcontent" alt="design" onmouseover="MM_effectAppearFade('tick1', 300, 0, 100, false)" onmouseout="MM_effectAppearFade('tick1', 300, 100, 0, false)"/>
      <area shape="rect" coords="977,57,1018,76" href="web.html" alt="web" target="ifcontent" onmouseover="MM_effectAppearFade('tick2', 300, 0, 100, false)" onmouseout="MM_effectAppearFade('tick2', 300, 100, 0, false)"/>
      <area shape="rect" coords="810,79,1016,98" href="wedding.html" target="ifcontent" alt="wedding invites" onmouseover="MM_effectAppearFade('tick3', 300, 0, 100, false)" onmouseout="MM_effectAppearFade('tick3', 300, 100, 0, false)"/>
      <area shape="rect" coords="936,100,1015,121" href="contactus.html" target="ifcontent" alt="contact us" onmouseover="MM_effectAppearFade('tick4', 300, 0, 100, false)" onmouseout="MM_effectAppearFade('tick4', 300, 100, 0, false)"/>
      <area shape="rect" coords="932,126,1016,142" href="contactus.html" target="ifcontent" alt="quote" onmouseover="MM_effectAppearFade('tick5', 300, 0, 100, false)" onmouseout="MM_effectAppearFade('tick5', 300, 100, 0, false)"/>
    </map>

    <div id="div_ticks">
    <table width="27" height="110" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td height="21"><img src="images/tick.png" name="tick1" width="21" height="6" id="tick1" onload="MM_showHideLayers('tick1','','hide')" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="21"><img src="images/tick.png" name="tick2" width="21" height="6" id="tick2" onload="MM_showHideLayers('tick2','','hide')" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="21"><img src="images/tick.png" name="tick3" width="21" height="6" id="tick3" onload="MM_showHideLayers('tick3','','hide')"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="21"><img src="images/tick.png" name="tick4" width="21" height="6" id="tick4" onload="MM_showHideLayers('tick4','','hide')"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="21"><img src="images/tick.png" name="tick5" width="21" height="6" id="tick5" onload="MM_showHideLayers('tick5','','hide')"/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
html, body {height: 100%;}

body {
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url(../images/main.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 228px;
}

#header {
    position: relative;
    width: 2000px;
    height: 456px;
    margin-left: -1000px;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
}

#ifcontent {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 610px;
    margin-left: -550px;
    left: 50%;
}

#footer {
    position: relative;
    width: 2000px;
    height: 228px;
    margin-left: -1000px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -228px;
    clear: both;
}

#div_ticks {
    position: absolute;
    width: 33px;
    height: 121px;
    z-index: 4;
    left: 1036px;
    top: 35px;
}

#footer_img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 115px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of most of your CSS here. You can center your elements without setting left:%50 a width and a negative margin. All you need to do is set the width of the element then set the left and right margin to auto.

```
#header {
    width:2000px; 
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I appreciate it. I've just tried that but then everything just snaps to the left of the page.

Comment: Take a look at this plunkr hopefully it helps. I added grayscale backgrounds to make it easier to see each element [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/cF3SecLLxfAuceyWNpKc?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

change header css to

```
    #header {
      width: 2000px;
      margin: auto;
      }
```

and add css for your objects

```
#header object {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
}
```